# Android Album art Animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-mediaplayer

I am developing a music player app in android in which i show albums in grid view.lately i came across this app where album art is shown as animation
[image: album art animation].

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what effect you want but I assume you mean coverflow. If you google for that you'll find some libraries that will help you implement it. Here are a couple.

https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow

https://github.com/Polidea/android-coverflow

Answer (score 0):

Here is the point.

First of all you need to use ViewPager with PageTransformer(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html) where you could define your animation.

Second step is overriding getPageWidth(return 0.2 for example) in PageAdapter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) now user can see more than one page in the same time.